# Tikz nodepart height

Tags: tikz-pgf

Hi I am creating a figure which contains a table with tikz

```
\begin{figure}[h!]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[rectangle split, rectangle split parts=6,
       draw, minimum width=4cm,font=\small,
       rectangle split part align={center}] (t1)
    {             AAAAA
     \nodepart{two}
                  AAAAbbbb
     \nodepart{three}
                  cccc
     \nodepart{four}
                  d sddas
     \nodepart{five}
                   AAA lsd eresf
     \nodepart{six}
                   lvxcxv};

\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{1} \label{fig:1}
\end{figure}
```

But the rectangles have different size according to the word inside them. Can I have a fixed size to the maximum of the rectangles? And how is this possible?

Comment: Since your rectangle splits vertically, `minimum height` will be ignored. You could add `\strut` (or a customized strut) to each part. You could create your table with a `\matrix` instead.

Comment: Can you share an example of matrix? There is no command to control the vertical height of the node?

Comment: Sure. Please see my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your rectangle splits vertically, `minimum height` will be ignored. You could add `\strut` (or a customized strut) to each part. Another option is to create your table with a `matrix of nodes` instead; in the last approach you have access to `minimum height` for the nodes.

Below I show four constructs: the original table, the table adding `\strut`; the table adding a customized `\Mstrut` and the table using a `matrix of nodes` with specified `minimum height` for the nodes:

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.multipart,matrix}

% for a customized strut
\newcommand\Mstrut{\rule[-7pt]{0pt}{20pt}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[rectangle split, rectangle split parts=6,
       draw, minimum width=4cm,font=\small,
       rectangle split part align={center},minimum height=70pt] (t1)
    {             AAAAA
     \nodepart{two}
                  AAAAbbbb
     \nodepart{three}
                  cccc
     \nodepart{four}
                  d sddas
     \nodepart{five}
                   AAA lsd eresf
     \nodepart{six}
                   lvxcxv};

\end{tikzpicture}\quad
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[rectangle split, rectangle split parts=6,
       draw, minimum width=4cm,font=\small,
       rectangle split part align={center},minimum height=70pt] (t1)
    {             \strut AAAAA
     \nodepart{two}
                  \strut AAAAbbbb
     \nodepart{three}
                  \strut cccc
     \nodepart{four}
                  \strut d sddas
     \nodepart{five}
                  \strut  AAA lsd eresf
     \nodepart{six}
                  \strut  lvxcxv};
\end{tikzpicture}\quad
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[rectangle split, rectangle split parts=6,
       draw, minimum width=4cm,font=\small,
       rectangle split part align={center},minimum height=70pt] (t1)
    {             \Mstrut AAAAA
     \nodepart{two}
                  \Mstrut AAAAbbbb
     \nodepart{three}
                  \Mstrut cccc
     \nodepart{four}
                  \Mstrut d sddas
     \nodepart{five}
                  \Mstrut  AAA lsd eresf
     \nodepart{six}
                  \Mstrut  lvxcxv};
\end{tikzpicture}\quad
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \matrix[
    matrix of nodes,
    nodes={minimum height=7ex,text width=4cm,align=center,draw},
    row sep=-\pgflinewidth
    ] (mat)
    {
      AAAAA \\
      AAAAbbbb \\
      cccc \\
      d sddas \\
      AAA lsd eresf \\
      lvxcxv \\
    };
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]